# How to remove emojis from a filename using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, filenames, emoji

How can I find and remove emojis from filenames with PowerShell?
For example, I want to remove emojis like  and .

I have tried the following code, but it does not work. It seems that PowerShell can't handle the utf32 encoding.

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse . | where {$_.Name -match "[\u1F600\u1F64F]"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex from this website: [Emojis in Javascript](https://reactnativecafe.com/emojis-in-javascript#Conclusion). I tried with a few different emotes and it seems to work fine.

Regex string:

```
(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|[\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|[\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|[\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])
```

Answer (score 3):

Emoji's are represented in powershell as 16-bit surrogate pairs in this range.  Codes like 0x1F600 are too high to represent in 16 bits, which is what powershell uses.  Emojis are actually 2 characters long.  Individually they're unprintable.  `-cmatch` is a precaution because there's a couple unicode characters that have lower case versions in the ascii range `İ K`.  It doesn't really make sense to use case insensitive -match with a unicode range anyway.  Note that a script encoded 'utf8 no bom' with non-ascii characters won't work in powershell 5.

```
# U+D800 to U+DBFF (called "high surrogate") gets combined with another 
# Unicode code point from range U+DC00 to U+DFFF (called "low surrogate")

echo hi > file
dir | where name -cmatch '[\uD800-\uDFFF]' | 
  rename-item -newname { $_.name -creplace '[\uD800-\uDFFF]' } -whatif

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item:
 C:\Users\js\foo\file Destination: C:\Users\js\foo\file".
```

[Surrogate Pairs and Variation Selectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/encoding/surrogate-pairs#:%7E:text=With%20surrogate%20pairs%2C%20a%20Unicode,over%20one%20million%20additional%20characters.)

Answer (score 0):

You can just paste the symbol (running on v5.1); I imagine if Windows can interpret it, then so can PowerShell.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUNDJ.png)

Comment: I know, that is possible. But doesn't solve my problem. I want to find filenames, with any emoji. This is why I tried with range.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I would've added a comment but can't until 50 rep :(
Perhaps you could filter using regex \W?

Comment: gci | ?{$_.name -match '[^ -~]+'}  
Appears to work well

Comment: Note: unless you save your script in the utf-bom format, your unicode will not be preserved.